# Multiple products in the same Grafana graph

Tags: dashboard, grafana

In Kibana it is possible to get data of multiple products or variants of a product into the same graph.

For example I have a product called service tool. This service tool has three variants called A, B and C. In Kibana it was possible to have the X axis separated into the three variants and in each section I was able to display multiple bars that represent the monthly revenue. By that, a graph contained the information about how much revenue each variant generated in the past months. Having an own bar for each month.

I wasn't able to set up such a graph in Grafana and the internet couldn't help me either. Is that even possible? With stacked bars it's possible but I would like to have them next to each other.

Thanks!